Only Trigger Apex when File is not uploaded via chatter feed on Case
I have an apex trigger that creates a Chatter post on a case when a file is uploaded to that case. The code is working perfectly fine, the issue is I want to be able to restrict this code to only run when the file is uploaded to case through any means EXCEPT when uploaded by way of Chatter post.
Is there a way to identify if a ContentVersion/ContentDocument/ContentDocumentLink was uploaded via chatter? I thought the Origin field on ContentVersion might be useful, however it seems all of the files have a value of "C" no matter what.
Here is my code:
public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {

public static void OnAfterInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlRecords){
    for(ContentDocumentLink a: cdlRecords){
        
        if(String.valueOf(a.LinkedEntityId).substring(0,3) == '500'){
            ContentDocument file = [SELECT Id, LatestPublishedVersionId
                                    FROM ContentDocument
                                    WHERE Id =: a.ContentDocumentId];
            
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.body = 'File Uploaded';
            post.parentId = a.LinkedEntityId;
            insert post;
            
            FeedAttachment postAttachment = new FeedAttachment();
            postAttachment.FeedEntityId = post.id;
            postAttachment.Type = 'Content';
            postAttachment.RecordId = file.LatestPublishedVersionId;
            insert postAttachment;
        }  
    }    
}
}


There is no way that I know that you can detect the nature of the content document upload, unless you create custom process for uploading files which marks the upload source (e.g upload button).
If the idea of your code is to post to chatter that a file has been uploaded, you could check the FeedAttachments related to Case records as associated with your CDL having a LinkedEntityId.
Untested code below, partially bulkified.
    public static void onAfterInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlRecords) {

    List<String> caseIds        = new List<String>();
    List<String> cdIds          = new List<String>();
    List<String> cvIds          = new List<String>();
    List<String> feedItemIds    = new List<String>();
    List<String> attachmentVers = new List<String>();
    List<String> toCreateIds    = new List<String>();

    for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdlRecords) {
        //is it attached to a case record
        if(String.valueOf(cdl.LinkedEntityId).substring(0,3) == '500') {
            caseIds.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);  //used to get feed items associated to case
            cdIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
        }
    }
    //get the content documents so we get the latest version info
    List<ContentDocument> cds = [SELECT Id, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :cdIds];
    //get the content version Ids so we can check Ids
    Map<Id, Id> mapVersionByDocumentId = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for (ContentDocument cd : cds ) {
        cvIds.add(cd.LatestPublishedVersionId);
        mapVersionByDocumentId.put(cd.Id, cd.LatestPublishedVersionId);
    }
    //Get feed items associated with the case(s)
    List<FeedItem> feedItems = [SELECT Id FROM FeedItem WHERE ParentId IN :caseIds];
    for (FeedItem fi : feedItems) {
        feedItemIds.add(fi.Id);
    }

    List<FeedAttachment> attachments = [SELECT Id, Type, RecordId FROM FeedAttachment WHERE Type = 'Content' AND FeedEntityId IN :feedItemIds];

    for (FeedAttachment fa : attachments) {
        attachmentVers.add(fa.RecordId);  //list of Id that are the latest published version Id which have feed items
    }

    Map<Id,Id> feedMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdlRecords) {
        if(mapVersionByDocumentId.containsKey(cdl.ContentDocumentId)) {  //
            if(attachmentVers.contains(mapVersionByDocumentId.get(cdl.ContentDocumentId))) {
                //do nothing as latest Version exists against a post
            } else {
                toCreateIds.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
                feedMap.put(cdl.LinkedEntityId,mapVersionByDocumentId.get(cdl.ContentDocumentId));
            }
        }
    }

    if(toCreateIds.size() >0) {
        List<FeedItem> feedItemsToCreate = new List<FeedItem> ();
        List<FeedAttachment> attachToCreate = new List<FeedAttachment>();
        for(String leId : toCreateIds) {
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.Body = 'File Uploaded';
            post.ParentId = leId;
            feedItemsToCreate.add(post);
        }
        insert feedItemsToCreate;
        for(FeedItem fi : feedItemsToCreate) {
            FeedAttachment postAttachment = new FeedAttachment();
            postAttachment.FeedEntityId = fi.id;
            postAttachment.Type = 'Content';
            postAttachment.RecordId = feedMap.get(fi.ParentId);
            attachToCreate.add(postAttachment);
        }
        insert attachToCreate;
    }
}


Hey Andy, thanks for your suggestion. I am close to getting this to work, the issue here though is that when the trigger on ContentDocumentLink fires, the FeedItem record doesn't exist. I tried creating a future method, but it seems that is not allowed. Any suggestions on how to get around this issue?
